# unable to find except package

Tags: software-installation

when I try the command

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)  except
```

I get the following error message

```
E: unable to locate package except.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: please post the command you tried along with it's output.

Comment: `except` does not seem to be a package available in Debian/Ubuntu, try to install `gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)` only

Comment: Are you sure of the writing `except`. Don't you mean `expect` ? Which an available command in Ubuntu from the package called `expect` (at least in 13.10).

Answer (score -1):

It is "expect" not except

try `apt-get install expect`

it is there in ubuntu/debian. I did same but it was misspelled by me, :)